# I'm trying to use pyttsx3 to create simple voice assistant but keep getting errors

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyttsx3

warnings.warn( Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/**init**.py", line 20, in init eng = _activeEngines[driverName] File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/weakref.py", line 134, in **getitem** o = self.datakey KeyError: 'sapi5' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/adityagupta/Desktop/Project/assistant.py", line 10, in  engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5') File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/**init**.py", line 22, in init eng = Engine(driverName, debug) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in **init** self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in **init** self._module = importlib.import_module(name) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked File "", line 855, in exec_module File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/sapi5.py", line 1, in  import comtypes.client # Importing comtypes.client will make the gen subpackage ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'comtypes'

```
listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to install the comtypes module.

pip install comtypes

Comment: @BendikKnapstad That's not the issue. `comtypes` would work on Windows only, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `sapi5` engine on macOS (which you're evidently using based on the paths in your traceback), since it's Windows only.

Based on [the documentation](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#pyttsx3.init) you can just elide the `sapi5` parameter to use a platform default, so:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init()
```